# Am I simulating correctly my hidden markov chain?

Tags: code-review

I want to simulate a hidden markov model, in which

$y_t|y_{t-1},x_t=i \sim N(\theta_0y_{t-1}+\theta_i,\sigma^2)$, where $y_t$ is the observations or data, and $x_t$ is the state variable of the hidden markov chain.

Here is my code:

```
markovchain[s0_, P_, n_] := Module[{condprob, list, counter, x},
   condprob = s0.P;
   x = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
   list = {s0};
   If[x > condprob[[1]], list = Append[list, {0, 1}], 
    list = Append[list, {1, 0}]];
   counter = 2;
   While[counter < n,
    x = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
    condprob = list[[counter]].P;
    If[x > condprob[[1]],
     list = Append[list, {0, 1}], list = Append[list, {1, 0}]
     ];
    counter++;
    ];
   Table[Position[list[[i]], 1][[1, 1]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
   ];
```

This is to create the hidden markov chain.

To simulate the data or observations I use the programme below which needs the markov chain programme above.

```
simulateme[n_, θ_, P_, sigma2_, initialdist_] := 
  Module[{lst, element, X, counter, mc, y, s0},

   y = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
   If[y > initialdist[[1]],
    s0 = {0, 1},
    s0 = {1, 0}
    ];
   lst = {RandomVariate[
      NormalDistribution[s0.{θ[[2]], θ[[3]]}, sigma2]]};
   mc = markovchain[s0, P, n];
   element = 1;
   While[element < n + 1,
    X = RandomVariate[
      NormalDistribution[θ[[
         mc[[element]] + 1]] + θ[[1]]*lst[[element]], sigma2]];
    lst = Append[lst, X];
    element++;
    ];
   lst[[2 ;; n + 1]]
   ];
```

What I would like to know is if there is anything wrong with my code. I'm using this for a work, and I would like to be sure that I'm not making any mistakes...

Comment: I would use some articles which have some simulation of Markov chains then I would simulate those to see if my code work. The other thing you can do is simulation of extreme examples and see if the result coincide with intuition. For example if I simulate the projection of an object on earth then I expect when there is no friction at angle of 45 degree I must get the longest range or in a 1D random walk if the probability of going to the left is zero I expect a random walk in one direction.

Comment: @yashar do you happen to have access to some of those articles?

Comment: Another way to check your code would be to compare to the built in commands such as `ContinuousMarkovChain` and/or `DiscreteMarkovChain`. `?*Markov*` will show a few more that might be useful.

Comment: @bills with those functions I can only check that my markovchain programme is correct. What about the other one?

P.S.: The commands are '*Process' instead of '*Chain'.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I don't know about Markov chains so I don't know about those articles. However, in my field I usually try the approach I wrote about.

Comment: @yashar Ok Thanks for the suggestion